# why does junit4 not have Assert.assertArrayEquals() for double[]s?

Tags: java, assert, junit4

There appear to be `Assert.assertArrayEquals()` methods in Junit4 for all primitives other than double, e.g.

```
Assert.assertArrayEquals(int[] expected, int[] actual)
```

and

```
Assert.assertArrayEquals(char[] expected, char[] actual)
```

but not

```
Assert.assertArrayEquals(double[] expected, double[] actual, double eps)
```

or

```
Assert.assertArrayEquals(double[] expected, double[] actual, double[] eps)
```

(the latter to account for variable ranges of doubles). Is there a fundamental reason why I should not write such a function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does have such a method (in 4.7), although it is not documented on the online javadoc [here](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc_40/index.html). It was certainly an oversight in the javadoc/version, but it is there now.

Answer (score 7):

The method seem to have been added in JUnit 4.6, but is for some reason missing in 4.5 and previous versions. I wouldn't expect any problems upgrading to a newer JUnit version.

Answer (score 1):

According to the JUnit bug database, they are "[working on it](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2095139&group_id=15278&atid=365278)". Based on other answers, it sounds like the bug database is not completely in sync with reality.

Answer (score 0):

just use:

```
 AssertTrue(**message**, Arrays.equals(**expected**,**result**)
```

You might need this to round your result values to test against expected:

```
 public double roundTo2Decimals(double val) {
    DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat("###.####");
    return Double.valueOf(df2.format(val));
}
```

See [javdoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) for more info